# Expectation of a distance in a triangle

Tags: probability

A point $x$ is uniformly distributed in an isosceles triangle with top angle $\alpha$, what is the expected distance of the point $x$ to the side opposite to angle $\alpha$.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
f(x,y) = \frac1{ h^2 \tan \alpha}, \qquad {(y-h) \tan \alpha} \leq x \leq {(h-y) \tan \alpha} , 0 \leq y \leq h
$$
$$
f(y) = \int f(x,y)dx = \frac{2(h-y)}{h^2}, \qquad 0 \leq y \leq h
$$

> $$
> \mathbb{E}[y] = \int yf(y)dy= \frac h3
> $$

Comment: Is $\frac12 h^2 \tan \alpha$ the area of the isosceles triangle or just half of it?

Comment: You are right. I corrected it.

Comment: @BabakS. What tag?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: For example, geometry? Indeed, it looks like a geo problem at the first sight. However, the OP didn't add such this tag. :)